# Class placing a instance of its self in static list located in the class

Tags: c#, static

Is this a common way to store instances in a list that can be accessed by any class. Are there any better Techniques to achieving this?

```
class fish
{

string species = "Gold Fish";

int age = 1;

public static list<fish> Listholder = new list<fish>();

Listholder.add(this);

}
```

Comment: `list` must be `List` if you mean the BCL one, and `fish` should be `Fish` according to MS coding standards.

Comment: That you have a bunch of fish that should be accessed by any class is, in itself, a big red flag and doesn't sound proper to me.  What are these fish, specifically?  Why is everyone needing to access it?

Comment: To clarify, please update the question describing how you expect `ListHolder` is to be used by other classes. In addition to what others pointed out about names, note that your `ListHolder` is not a holder of a list but a list itself; `fishes` or `fishList` is better name.

Comment: +1 to @Servy - just 'cause your comment is hilarious! Brian: I'm presuming this is just a quick example for your question, since you don't even have any constructors, methods, etc in your class. Your idea should work - as to how common it is, though... maybe if you explain more about what you're trying to do, we could offer some alternatives that would be "best practice".

Comment: Well this was a example of a the system i'm using to for Colonels and Captains each respective country will have its own static list. that can be accessed by the particular GameObject in unity. Not breaking the rules of encapsulation is a goal of mine but sometimes following these rules effect performance of the game.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I generally avoid static variables and methods but in this case Specific country have there own specific captains and Colonels. The class will randomly generate a captains/colonels of various skill level. The AI will place the object as arrangement of a method.

Comment: so you are going to want the game to dynamically create new `captains and colonels` on the fly and add them to the list?

Comment: Yep, and because I started reading GOK after I started this project my patterns are rather scattered and messy.

Comment: you are going to have to set up a Seperate class/function that creates the objects when something happens and add them to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` is not thread safe, so if you want to add/remove fishs from different threads you should use [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) instead.

For example:

```
public class Fish
{
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    private static System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Fish> Aquarium = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<Fish>();

    static Fish()
    {
        var goldFish = new Fish { Age = 1, Species = "Gold Fish" };
        PutFishIntoAquarium(goldFish);
    }

    public static void PutFishIntoAquarium(Fish fish)
    {
        Aquarium.Add(fish);
    }

    public static void ClearAquarium()
    {
        Fish someFish;
        while (!Aquarium.IsEmpty)
        {
            TryTakeFishOutOfAquarium(out someFish);
        }
    }

    public static bool TryTakeFishOutOfAquarium(out Fish fish)
    {
        if (Aquarium.TryTake(out fish))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool TryLookAtSomeFish(out Fish fish)
    {
        if (Aquarium.TryPeek(out fish))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I probably wrote my code all wrong, especially trying to longhand the `get;set;` been a while since I wrote my own code,  been fixing other people's code for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to get at is a way to store a globally accessible list of fish somewhere.  I.e. to have a central repository of fish that all other classes get their fish from.

If this is so, there are other ways of doing this such as the Service/[Repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).  Keep in mind that having a mutable public static field will make testing and re-usability harder.

Answer (score -1):

a Class has Properties.

the class allows you to create objects.

```
class fish()
{
    Private String _Type;
    Private Int _Age;
    Private String _Species;

    Public Type
    {
        get _Type;
        set _Type = Value;
    }
    Public Age
    {
        get _Age;
        set _Age = Value;
    }
    Public Species
    {
        get _Species;
        set _Species = Value;
    }
    public new(string Type, Int Age, String Species)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Species = Species;
    }
}

//this is your new object.
Fish SunFish = New Fish("small", 9, "Sunfish");
```

after creating an object you can create a list of objects

Comment: The OP's not looking to create any arbitrary `List<Fish>`, he's looking to have a new `Fish` automatically add itself to the list.

Comment: I am thinking that the OP needs to create a different functionality to add `fish` or `captains` to the list, and that the list needs to be a set of pre-made objects. like say when someone in his game gets to a certain level then he needs the game/application to create a new `fish/captain` and add it to the list. that needs to be a different process altogether

Comment: Something Like that will be implemented when the other team members finish some important parts of the game. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: the other team members may need to know that this class and the list of `captains/fish` is available to them to use. you should probably set this stuff up right away and give them their `in/out` scenario.